# xfce4 loses title bars on all windows

Tags: debian, xfce, gdm3

I'm running `Debian Wheezy` using `gdm3` as window manager and `xfce4` as desktop environment.

Every so often, when I login, the desktop environment starts OK, but all windows are missing the title bar and are positioned at location (0,0).

Usually logging out and back in, or restarting `gdm3` and logging in, fixes it, but today it didn't. I switched to 'GNOME classic' which works fine, indicating it's probably a setting in `xfce4` that's got corrupted.

Short of just zapping every file in `.config/` and `.cache/` which refers to `xfce`, is there a simple fix/edit?

Comment: Sounds a bit like xfwm crashed and never got restarted.

Comment: Is there a log file to indicate why it's crashing (or failing to start)?

Comment: That would probably depend on your set-up but `~/.xsession-errors` might have something useful, or maybe the `/var/log/Xorg.*log` files.

Comment: nothing obvious in `~/.xsession-errors' but simply restarting `xfwm4` from a terminal seems to fix it (even across logouts/logins).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xfce's window manager crashed for some reason and the simple fix is to run `xfwm4` in a terminal.

If you can't do it in X (because, e.g., the panels/menus are unavailable, Alt+F2 doesn't work), switch to a virtual console (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F2), login, and type `DISPLAY=:0 xfwm4 --daemon`.

(Use Ctrl+Alt+F7 to switch back to X.)

Comment: That was @jw013's answer (in a comment) but he never posted it as an answer, so, while correct, I cannot give you credit for it.

Comment: I'm sorry, AFAIK, the convention is to provide solutions as answers, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to my wife's xfce machine, which I fixed by deleting some file under .config/xfce4 but when I lost all my title bars on my machine today I couldn't remember which one.

Just read the post above, so opened a terminal and typed:

> xfwm4

everything came back :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found that running: xfwm4 ...from the terminal, restored title bars and controls.

Using: xfwm4 --replace ...from the term., fixed the prob. even after restart.

NOTE:

From previous answer from K3---rnc...

...this worked for me the first time...but did not stick on
reboot and was frustratingly painful to do on each boot:

If you can't do it in X (because, e.g., the panels/menus are unavailable, Alt+F2 doesn't work), switch to a virtual console (e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F2), login, and type DISPLAY=:0 xfwm4 --daemon.

(Use Ctrl+Alt+F7 to switch back to X.)